# Find the value of $(1-2\alpha_1)(1-2\alpha_2)\dots (1-2\alpha_6)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_6$ are roots of $x^6+x^2+1=0$, then find the value of $(1-2\alpha_1)(1-2\alpha_2)\dots (1-2\alpha_6)$.

My attempt:

From the given equation we have, $S_1=0,S_2=0,S_3=0,S_4=1,S_5=0,S_6=1$. ($S_k$ is the sum of the products of the elements of $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_6 \}$ taken $k$ at a time).

$\prod^6_{i=1}(y-a_i)=y^6-S_1'y^5+S_2'y^4-S_3'y^3+S_4'y^2-S_5'y+S_6'$. ($S_k$ is the sum of the products of the elements of $\{a_k:a_k=2\alpha_k\}$ taken $k$ at a time.)

Putting $y=1$ in the above equation, we get, $\prod^6_{i=1}(1-a_i)=1-S_1'+S_2'-S_3'+S_4'-S_5'+S_6'=1-2S_1+4S_2-8S_3+16S_4-32S_5+64=1-0+0-0+16-0+64=81$

Is my process correct? What are some other methods to solve this question?

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$x^6+x^2+1=\prod_{i=1}^6(x-\alpha_i).$$

Put $x=0.5$ and multiply $2^6$,
$$\prod_{i=1}^6(1-2\alpha_i)=2^6\prod_{i=1}^6(0.5-\alpha_i)=2^6\left(0.5^6+0.5^2+1\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

If the $\alpha_k$ are roots of $x^6+x^2+1$, then the $1-2\alpha_k$ are roots of

$$\left(\frac{1-x}2\right)^6+\left(\frac{1-x}2\right)^2+1.$$

The extreme terms of this polynomial are

$$\frac{x^6}{2^6}$$ and $$\frac1{2^6}+\frac1{2^2}+1$$ and by Vieta the product of the roots is the ratio of the coefficients, $81$.

---

For the sum of these numbers,

$$-\frac{-\dfrac 6{2^6}}{\dfrac1{2^6}}=6,$$

which is simply $6\cdot1-2\cdot0$, where $0$ is the sum of the roots of the original polynomial.